# How do I call a parent procedure's variable in netlogo

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

In netlogo I have a procedure that calls another procedure. How can I go about getting the value

for example, I have two breeds of agents, a hub and a link. A hub has a local variable called 'budget' and I'm trying to modify its value.

```
hubs-own [
  budget
]

to go
  ask hub 0 [
    do-ivalue
  ]
end

to do-ivalue
  ask links [
    ;; I'm trying to set the local variable budget of the hub that's calling this link
    set self.budget newvalue ;; this is obviously wrong, how can I fix this?
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you want to do is use is 'myself', it refers to the caller (asker): the one who asked to run the code where the 'myself' is located.

```
to do-ivalue   
  ask links [
    ask myself [set budget 10]   ] 
end
```

The 'self' refers to the agent running the code. It is similar to 'this' in Java.

Comment: so if I replace 'myself' with 'self' it would then refer to the individual link?

Comment: yes, 'self' would be the link. It would be silly, since 'ask self [doit]' is the same as 'doit', except maybe if you hear voices in your head telling you to do things.

Answer (score 0):

hmm. 
not sure why u want to do it this way..
what u can do for now is

ask links[
 let new_value new_value_from_link
 ask hubs[
   set budget new_value
 ]
]

Comment: Hi Badoet, that would be a good alternative but I'd like to find out how to call the parent's variable in case I ever need it.